# View "Entry view tracking" in CP content entries

Tags: control-panel, admin, content, admin.php

Is it possible to display the view count of certain channels in the CP content overview?

I am currently displaying these view count to my user on their overview page, but I am unable to add this field in the admin overview page (where I can view/edit all the entries of all the users).

I would prefer it if I didn't need to use a plugin to do so.

Comment: Assuming you're on EE6, are you currently using View Tracking to track views on an entry and then displaying that in a widget on the user's dashboard?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm doing. And I want to get that info on the cp aswell